# Login keyring prompt appears twice on login

Tags: login, password, keyrings

Whenever I log into my Ubuntu desktop machine, a password dialogue appears for the login keyring. Once I've entered the password, it comes up again (and this isn't because I got it wrong the first time).

The password is the same as my account password, so what's going on?

**Update:** This is what it looks like (I get two of these in succession):

[image]

Comment: It's trying to unlock something else, and it's also a bug on it not remembering the password.

Comment: Does it ask for the default password?

Comment: @Alvar: See screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You did not say if you change your password (login) recently?

If you did it is a bet that a second folder in Password and Encryption (the keyring application) still answer to the old password.

You can change the password on the folder to the new password.

Comment: The only folder/keyring there is called "login", and both password prompts look exactly like the screenshot (i.e. they both refer to the "login" keyring). I did change my password a while back, but I updated it on the keyring too; like I said, the passwords are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have multiple WiFi connections that are not available to all users.