# How do I fix faulty Software Center and Software Updater in 13.10? (Novice Level User)

Tags: upgrade, software-center, update-manager

I asked this question before with older version of OS, but it is happening again with 13.10 and the same steps I took to resolve it by moving statoverride.bad last time didn't work this time. Here is my command line error.

```
Setting up rsyslog (5.8.11-2ubuntu4) ...
chown: invalid group: ‘syslog:adm’
dpkg: error processing rsyslog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-minimal:
 ubuntu-minimal depends on rsyslog; however:
  Package rsyslog is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ubuntu-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                           Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsyslog
 ubuntu-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Open a terminal by pressing ctrl and alt and t at the same time. A purple box with text in it will come up.

Type the following :

sudo apt-get install rsyslog

Enter your password (it will be invisible on the screen so don't worry if nothing appears!) and press return

Then type :

sudo apt-get update

and  press enter.

Then close the terminal and try to install your program from the software center again.

Comment: new error - subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-minimal:
 ubuntu-minimal depends on rsyslog; however:
  Package rsyslog is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ubuntu-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsyslog
 ubuntu-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Well, it seems that the software updater is working nonetheless. I did exactly as instructed and then checked out the updater interface and it said that my software is up to date. The error is in running an upgrade. Perhaps that is unnecessary right now since I just installed 13.10. For some reason I thought there was a 13.11. Thank you.

Comment: If you continue to have problems you should install Synaptic Package Manager from the Software Center. That will spot any broken packages and remove the problems for you.

Comment: I tried the SPM and still cannot update. Update login keyring keeps popping up, but I am not typing in my password, but cancelling it instead. Is this related? I am getting the same rsyslog error.

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but other people have had problems with login keyrings. Here's one link http://askubuntu.com/questions/51378/login-keyring-prompt-appears-twice-on-login but it may not be exactly the same problem as yours. You should search this site or the ubuntu forums with error messages like that and see what other people have done. Hope you get it all fixed!

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. My real issue has to do with wi-fi and vulnerability that most users probably don't encounter. My browser gets corrupted immediately and it affects my online accounts, in particular Google and Facebook.